# MKMapItem not showing correct info on MKPlacemark

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkmapitem

I get the results of a `MKLocalSearch` and it includes something like...

```
{
    address =     {
        formattedAddressLine =         (
            "Marton Road",
            Middlesbrough,
            TS1,
            England
        );
        structuredAddress =         {
            administrativeArea = England;
            areaOfInterest =             (
                "Great Britain"
            );
            country = "United Kingdom";
            countryCode = GB;
            fullThoroughfare = "Marton Road";
            geoId =             (
            );
            locality = Middlesbrough;
            postCode = TS1;
            subAdministrativeArea = Middlesbrough;
            thoroughfare = "Marton Road";
        };
    };
    addressGeocodeAccuracy = 0;
    business =     (
                {
            UID = 9301704419119613323;
            URL = "http://www.cineworld.co.uk";
            attribution =             (
                                {
                    attributionURLs =                     (
                        "yelp5.3:///biz/cineworld-middlesbrough",
                        "yelp4:///biz/cineworld-middlesbrough",
                        "yelp:///biz/cineworld-middlesbrough",
                        "http://yelp.com/biz/cineworld-middlesbrough"
                    );
                    sourceIdentifier = "com.yelp";
                    sourceVersion = 1;
                }
            );
            canBeCorrectedByBusinessOwner = 1;
            name = Cineworld;
            source =             (
                                {
                    "source_id" = "b2LOPag6ha6845__dgXehw";
                    "source_name" = yelp;
                },
                                {
                    "source_id" = 6670;
                    "source_name" = tribune;
                },
                                {
                    "source_id" = 2000000103009680;
                    "source_name" = "acxiom_intl";
                },
                                {
                    "source_id" = "cineworld-middlesbrough";
                    "source_name" = "yelp_alias";
                }
            );
            "star_rating" =             (
                0
            );
            telephone = "+448712002000";
        }
    );
    center =     {
        lat = "54.57633773904653";
        lng = "-1.228197113614671";
    };
    inputLanguage = en;
    localSearchProviderID = 9902;
    mapRegion =     {
        eastLng = "-1.224891596539819";
        northLat = "54.57545000290778";
        southLat = "54.5738619816233";
        westLng = "-1.227631256834202";
    };
    name = Cineworld;
    type = 57;
}
```

Now when I add it to my map with...

```
id <MKAnnotation> annotation = mapItem.placemark;

[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

It adds a pin that, when I tap on it shows "Marton Road" but I'd like it to show "Cineworld".

I'm finding it really hard to find any info on getting stuff out of the `MKMapItem` and into the `MKPlacemark` though.

If I try to use `mapItem.name` in the place mark then they all show "United States".

Any idea how I can get some more useful information out of this?

Comment: This is likely an annotation reuse issue. Can you show the code you use in - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {}?

Comment: I'm not using that. Literally the two lines above are all I use to put the pins on the map.

Comment: I would look into that more then, like UITableViewCells, map view's reuse annotations and any appeared duplication/incorrect information is usually caused by reuse problems.

Comment: On second thought, you're only using one annotation? Do an NSLog on the mapItem object before you add the annotation and share what the result is. Are you sure the above information you showed is what you're actually getting?

Comment: The MKPlacemark returns the address for its `title` property and the MKPlacemark class doesn't let you set the `title` yourself.  What you can do is create an MKPointAnnotation (which has a settable `title` property) and set its title to whatever you want like mapItem.name.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617414/create-a-title-for-annotation-from-mklocalsearch.

Comment: @Mike the code in the question is an NSLog of the MKMapItem. Thanks

Comment: @Anna thanks. I'll give that a try in the morning :-)

Comment: @Anna, I agree this is likely the issue. Nice catch.

Comment: @Anna awesome! Just tried it and it works perfectly :D Thanks. If you want to add it as an answer I'll accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MKPlacemark` returns the address for its `title` property and the `MKPlacemark` class doesn't let you set the `title` yourself.

What you can do is create an `MKPointAnnotation` (which has a settable `title` property) and set its `title` to whatever you want like `mapItem.name`.

For example:

```
MKPointAnnotation *pa = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
pa.title = mapItem.name;
pa.coordinate = mapItem.placemark.coordinate;
[self.mapView addAnnotation:pa];
```

**Note:**
You don't have to use the `MKPointAnnotation` class (it's just the most convenient available).
You can also use a custom class that conforms to `MKAnnotation` and that has a settable `title` property (or some class that returns the `MKMapItem`'s `name` as its `title`).

Also note that if you want to be able to access the related `MKMapItem` or `MKPlacemark` in the annotation you add after-the-fact (eg. in the map view delegate methods), you'll need to use a custom class instead of `MKPointAnnotation` where you add a "sourceMapItem" or "sourcePlacemark" property that you can set when creating the annotation.

This way, you can set the `title` as needed but still access all the original `MKMapItem` or `MKPlacemark` values from which the annotation object was created (you couldn't do this easily if you use just `MKPointAnnotation` since it doesn't keep a reference to the source map item or placemark).